# Not Receiving data from Device if Socket is not closed

Tags: java, sockets

I am sending data from a device every min through TCP/IP socket.

I am 1. Opening client socket. 2. Sending Packet. 3. Closing Socket.

I am closing socket for every packet. If I didnt close the client socket I was unable to receive data.

Any suggestions

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? can you describe more?

Comment: I am not receiving any data to the configured port. If I dont close the client socket after every packet.

Answer (score 1):

When you close a socket, you also flush it's buffered data.  If you have buffered data you should expect to not see all (possibly any) data if you don't flush() or close() the stream.

In your case, I suspect you just need to flush() the output.

Comment: Can we force a socket to send the data in its buffer?

Comment: @user3616287 yes, use flush().  If you are concerned about Nangle's algorithm you can turn them off with `setTCPNoDelay(true)`